# How can I use the sp variable in the if at the top?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a Minecraft Bukkit plugin, using [this](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/noteblockapi/) API.
The problem I'm having is that I want to use the sp variable in the code below, to check if it is playing using .isplaying() (a method of the API), in the if-statement at the top. The problem is, is that the sp variable is created inside the if-statement. So how can I use that sp variable in the if-statement when the method is ran again?

If I'm not clear enough, tell me.
Also I'm pretty new to java, so bear that in mind.

-JustRamon

```
public void playTune(String eventTune, Player p)
{
    if (Methods.getSongPath(eventTune).exists()) //&& sp.isplaying()
    {
            Song s = NBSDecoder.parse(Methods.getSongPath(eventTune));
            SongPlayer sp = new RadioSongPlayer(s);
            sp.setAutoDestroy(true);
            sp.addPlayer(p);
            sp.setPlaying(true);
    }
    else
    {
            notFound(eventTune);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think again: you want to create an object only if some condition is true. On the other hand you want that object to already exist when checking that condition. That simply doesnt work. Just put a second if in your then-block that checks on sp as soon as it has been created. Btw: dont use single-character names. They tell nothing. Better call them player or songPlayer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to access the object with multiple calls to your method, you want a reference to the object. So you should declare a variable inside your *class* like so:

```
private SongPlayer sp;
```

Then change your method as follows:

```
public void playTune(String eventTune, Player p)
{
    /*Creates sp if it is null (When it is null, we know that there is no
    RadioSongPlayer object referenced by sp)*/
    if (Methods.getSongPath(eventTune).exists()) && sp == null)
    {
            Song s = NBSDecoder.parse(Methods.getSongPath(eventTune));
            sp = new RadioSongPlayer(s);
            sp.setAutoDestroy(true);
            sp.addPlayer(p);
            sp.setPlaying(true);
    }
    else
    {
            notFound(eventTune);
    }
    //Now that sp is not null, we know that it references a SongPlayer object, that is,
    //the object we just created in the first if statement
    if(sp != null){ /
        //sp was created
        //Use sp
    }
}
```

I won't recommend you to do this tho. It will be better to refactor your first `if` to another method because creating a `SongPlayer` shouldn't be a concern of your `playTune` method.